# List size is 0 on Glassfish whereas on tomcat , it works

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, glassfish

I have a a method which return the last index in a list. When I run the application on tomcat, it works fine. But when I run it on glassfish,I got the following error:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

This is the method which is returning the last value in a list:

```
    public String getLastValue(String code){

    List<Cars> car=new ArrayList<Cars>();
    try{
        car = new ArrayList<Cars>(carsDAO.findCarById(code));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
    }

    List<String> temp= new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Cars cars : car){
            temp.add(cars.getValue());
        }
    system.out.print("Size of car":+ temp.size());

    Collections.sort(temp);
    return temp.get(temp.size()-1);

}
```

STACKTRACE:

```
       type Exception report

       message

       descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented    it from fulfilling this request.

       exception

      javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:  Index: 5, Size: 0
      root cause

      javax.faces.el.EvaluationException:    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0
      root cause

      java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0
```

As you can see, I print the size of the list. On glassfish the size is 0 but on tomcat it returns me the correct number of data. How come it does not work on glassfish?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code? You check for size()!=0 hence you shouldn't get an Exception, and if temp is empty, then car is empty, and your System.out.print shouldn't run.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the message and the stacktrace for the exception, and indicate which line of your code is triggering the exception.

Comment: @JP and @ Kenster , I update the code as it was originally with the stacktrace on glassfish.

Comment: The error is not where you think it is. In your code, only the last line can give an IndexOutOfBoundsException. But if temp.size()==0, then the index would -1, but the error tells you the index is 5. So this line of code cannot give that exception.

Comment: Well for testing purpose I was returning  return temp.get(5); instead of  return temp.get(temp.size()-1); That's why I got index 5. The list contain 6 items( 0-5)

Comment: so car is empty, according to your code. So either you get an error earlier on and you don't see it (System.out.println("Error:"...)) or your database returned nothing. Are you sure you're connecting to the right db with the right user? And that the input data is the same on Tomcat?